# Dirichlet inverse for $\left\{1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,\ldots\right\}$

Tags: arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-convolution

I am looking for the Dirichlet inverse of $\left\{1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,\ldots\right\}$ or equivalently
$$
f(n)=\frac{ {i^{n-1}+(-i)^{n-1}}}{2}.
$$
It is an interesting inverse, it seems always to evaluate to $\pm1,0$, i.e. $f^{-1}(n) \in \left\{-1,0,1\right\}$. An explicit formula for $f^{-1}(n)$ would help me.

Comment: Just a remark: $f(n)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}n)$ and the corresponding Dirichlet series is the Dirichlet beta function. So $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{f^{ - 1} (n)}}{{n^s }}}  = \prod\limits_{p > 2} {\bigg( {1 - \frac{{( - 1)^{\frac{{p - 1}}{2}} }}{{p^s }}} \bigg)} .
$$

Comment: By the above observation, $$
f^{ - 1} (n) = ( - 1)^{\sum\nolimits_{j = 1}^k {\frac{{p_j  + 1}}{2}} } 
$$ when $n$ is the product of $k$ distinct odd primes $p_1,\ldots,p_k$, and $f^{-1}(n)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: It seems there is some relation to $mod \, 4$ behavior. If we note $p \% 4=3$ as "s" (smaller than multiple of 4) and $p \% 4=1$ as "g" (grater than multiple of 4) then for $f^{-1}(n)=+1$ and $k=1$ (only one factor) we have "s", for $k=2$  (two factors) we have "ss" or "gg", for $k=3$ (three factors) we have "sss" or "sgg".. and it is unclear to me how it generalizes to more factors. This is presumably equivalent to your formula.

Comment: Yes, it boils down to the exponents of $(-1)$ appearing in the sum. For "s" it gives a $+1$ factor and for the case $g$ it gives a $-1$ factor. So for example, if $n=ssgs$, then $f^{-1}(n)= 1\cdot 1\cdot(-1)\cdot 1=-1$ (provided the prime factors are different).

Comment: You should probably post your ideas as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{f(n)}}{{n^s }}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{(2n + 1)^s }}}  = \beta (s) = \prod\limits_{p > 2} {\left( {1 + ( - 1)^{\frac{{p + 1}}{2}} p^s } \right)^{ - 1} } ,
$$
where $\beta$ is the Dirichlet beta function and the Euler product is over the odd primes. Consequently,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{f^{ - 1} (n)}}{{n^s }}}  = \prod\limits_{p > 2} {\left( {1 + ( - 1)^{\frac{{p + 1}}{2}} p^s } \right)} .
$$
Expanding the product on the right-hand side, we see that
$$
f^{ - 1} (n) = ( - 1)^{\sum\nolimits_{p|n} {\frac{{p + 1}}{2}} } 
$$
when $n$ is an odd, [square-free integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) and $f^{-1} (n)=0$ otherwise.